# Objects, their instances and setTimeOut effect

Tags: javascript, object, greasemonkey, settimeout

So i am trying to learn object oriented programming in javascript.

```
function doStock() {    //my class
var that = this;
var nAntiFreeze = null;   // timeout ID
var getContent = function(oInPageContainer) {  
    GM_log('Antifreeze, before clear ' +nAntiFreeze);
    //clearTimeout(nAntiFreeze);
    GM_log('Antifreeze, after clear ' +nAntiFreeze);
};

return {
    sLink : "",
    oList : "",
    sSplitOperator : ";",
    reset : function() {
        this.sLink = '';
        this.oList = '';
        this.sSplitOperator = ';';
        nAntiFreeze = null;
    },
    loadPage : function() {
        if (this.sLink.length == 0) return;
        if (this.oList.length == 0) return;
        nAntiFreeze = setTimeout(function(){GM_log(that); that.loadPage();},30000);
        GM_log('antifreeze ' + nAntiFreeze);
        getPageAsync2(this.sLink,false,getContent);  //GM_xmlhttprequest
    }
}
```

};

My script runs on GreaseMonkey in FireFox 4. In my code i am using the above function/class to make an object as follows.

```
var oStocker = new doStock();
oStocker.sLink = 'www.somepage.com';
oStocker.oList = 'some list, may be a string line or the array object';
oStocker.loadPage();
```

`getPageAsync2` function calls GM_xmlhttprequest and then returns the result page contents inside a div container to the callback function.

First, general question: value of nAntiFreeze does not get reset to null or anything after i call `clearTimeOut` function. Is this normal?

Second question: why when the timeout runs out, i get the error `that.loadPage() is not a function`? GM_log(that) tells me [object Object].

A person on this question was able to make it work by using `var that = this`. But why is it not working for me? 
[Custom Object calling Methods with setTimeout loses scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335049/custom-object-calling-methods-with-settimeout-loses-scope)

**EDIT:** Third question: What happens if i create a million objects. Will browser get rid of them when they are done working? Because i sure am unable to free them as this object uses asynchronous ajax calls, which means that i can't do

```
var oStocker = new doStock();
oStocker.loadPage();
oStocker = null;
```

The oStocker = null will be called before my object even finished working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `nAntiFreeze` is a primitive value returned by `setTimeout`. You pass that value back to `clearTimtout` so it knows which timeout to clear. Calling `clearTimeout` doesn't affect the value of `nAntiFreeze`.

Secondly, `that.loadPage` is undefined because `that` references `this` when `doStock()` is called (where it is called as a constructor with `new`, it references a new Object). But your function doesn't return that object (i.e. the constructor's `this`), it returns the object after `return` that the `loadPage()` function is a method of. In other words, you are referencing the wrong object.

When you call `oStocker.loadPage()`, its `this` keyword references the `oStocker` object, but the function passed to setTimeout is referencing `that`, which has a closure to the constructor's `this`.

The following should work:

```
loadPage : function() {

    // Declare that here
    var that = this;

    if (this.sLink.length == 0) return;
    if (this.oList.length == 0) return;

    // If called as oStocker.loadPage(), this (and that) is
    // the oStocker object.
    nAntiFreeze = setTimeout(function(){GM_log(that); that.loadPage();},30000);
    GM_log('antifreeze ' + nAntiFreeze);
    getPageAsync2(this.sLink,false,getContent);  //GM_xmlhttprequest
}
```

There isn't much point using a constructor that doesn't return its `this`, you can use Richard Cornford's module pattern and use closures for inheritance.