# problems getting javascript and to degrade gracefully - image scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

I'm trying to create a javscript scroller following the example at: http://www.deadmarshes.com/Blog/jQuery+Slideshow+with+Crossfade.html

Unfortunately this version doesn't show anything when javascript is disabled but I'd like it to at least show the first image and caption and then just not move.

I stuck together a fiddle which, although the images loaded up before I added the JS it doesn't seem to work at the moment. All the code's there though and I am a bit stupid so I'm probably missing something simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lew7H/2/

Does anyone know how to make the initial transition not happen and just have the first 'slide' there?

Also I adapted this slightly to show 4 slides instead of 3. I changed 3 to 4 in two places in the JS (where it's keeping tally) and that seemed to work alright but now in FF when you click on a few of the numbers to change slides a few times then let it go back to normal running, the indicator which is meant to show which slide you're on starts appearing all over the place.

I assume that's to do with the way it's being counted in the JS but I haven't a clue what it's doing to be honest.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Just looking at the second issue there about the indicators screwing up after clicking on a few of them. The timing of the transitions also goes weird. It's like clicking a couple of times means the transitions and the pointers are going a couple of times. IE there's more than one bit of JS moving the slides and pointers, resulting in strangly timed transitions and more than one pointer. Could that be possible?

Comment: Hey everyone, I'm still trying to figure this out. Does anyone have any useful advise?

Comment: Is anyone able to help me figure this out? At least point me in the right direction :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed few calling part where you lose the scope. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335175/297641 to learn more about it.

**Fixed fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lew7H/12/

Take a look at the code and let me know if something is missing.

Comment: Hurray! That does indeed seem to be it! I've bought myself a big book on javascript and when I'm finnished I'm going to read it back to front. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

now Working See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lew7H/3/)

you forgot select Framework

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Although the images appear it doesn't transition like it's meant to. Also noticed the 3rd image isn't there because of a renegade whitespace just before the image filename in the html

Comment: Hey there. I tried your new JS code but it doesn't transition automatically at all :( did I miss something?

Comment: i will try but same code past from site but this one also not work [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/sezsM/) it will dive error $$ is not defined